# How to properly perform numeric comparison with strings in batch script

Tags: batch-file

*I don't know what's wrong with the script, but it always return false if the input value is greater than 1, and there's no output at all if the input value is less than 1.*

**Example**

```
@echo off

echo [1] Option 1
echo [2] Option 2
echo [3] Option 3
echo [4] Option 4
echo [5] Option 5
echo [6] Option 6
echo [7] Option 7
echo [8] Option 8
echo [9] Option 9
echo [10] Option 10

set /p option="Enter option (1-10): "

if "%option%" geq "1" if "%option%" leq "10" (
  echo %option% is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
) else (
  echo Invalid option %option%
)

pause >nul
```

**Input**

```
2
```

**Output**

```
Invalid option 2
```

**Expected Result**

```
2 is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
```

Comment: Note: Even with double quotes removed from the comparisons, if the 1st `if` is false, then the `else` will not happen, as the `else` is bound to the 2nd `if`. To correct this, nest the 2nd `if` and have another `else` bound for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks to do numeric comparisons:

```cmd
set /p option="Enter option (1-10): "

if %option% geq 1 if %option% leq 10 (
    echo %option% is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
) else (
    echo Invalid option %option%
)
```

With quotation marks you are forcing string comparisons, because actually they are also part of the compared values. If any of them is non-numeric (which is the case if one of them or both contain quotes), string or alphabetic comparison is used, where `2` is greater than `10`, because the character `2` has got a higher code than `1`.

---

This approach fails if the input value `%option%` is empty; you can counteract using `if defined`:

```cmd
:LOOP
rem // Reset variable, so it is empty if user just presses {Enter}:
set "option="
set /P option="Enter option (1-10): "
rem // Jump back to prompt if user did not enter anything:
if not defined option goto :LOOP
if %option% geq 1 if %option% leq 10 (
    echo %option% is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
) else (
    echo Invalid option %option%
)
```

Or you can force the value to be numeric by trying to convert using `set /A`; this is safer than the former variant, because it even works in case the user entry contains `"` and other special characters:

```cmd
set "option="
set /P option="Enter option (1-10): "
rem // Convert user entry to numeric value:
set /A "comp=option"
if %comp% geq 1 if %comp% leq 10 (
    echo %option% is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
) else (
    echo Invalid option %option%
)
```

Of cource [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) can be used as well to avoid troubles with empty values or special characters:

```cmd
set "option="
set /P option="Enter option (1-10): "
rem // Delayed expansion even allows to compare empty values and even to safely echo all possible strings:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if !option! geq 1 if !option! leq 10 (
    echo !option! is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
) else (
    echo Invalid option !option!
)
endlocal
```

---

Let us now focus on the `if` condition itself (with delayed expansion here) and rewrite it a bit:

```cmd
if !option! geq 1 (
    if !option! leq 10 (
        echo !option! is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
    ) else (
        echo Invalid option !option!
    )
)
```

Now you can clearly see that the case when `!option!` is less than `1` is not handled; to do so you will need another `else` clause:

```cmd
if !option! geq 1 (
    if !option! leq 10 (
        echo !option! is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
    ) else (
        echo Invalid option !option!
    )
) else (
    echo Invalid option !option!
)
```

Or you simply use [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) to accomplish the same:

```cmd
if !option! geq 1 if !option! leq 10 goto :NEXT
echo Invalid option !option!
goto :EOF
:NEXT
echo !option! is greater than or qual to 1, and is less than or equal to 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it a little more dynamically, for example:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set Option[ 2^>Nul')Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr "^::" "%~f0"^|FindStr /N "^"')Do Set "Option[%%A]=%%B"&Echo(%%A %%B
Set Option[>Nul 2>&1||Exit /B
Echo( Select an option from the list&Echo(
:Opt
::Option 1
::Option 2
::Option 3
::Option 4
::Option 5
::Option 6
::Option 7
::Option 8
::Option 9
::Option 10
Set /P "Opt="
Set Option[|Findstr /BL "Option[%Opt%]=">Nul||GoTo :Opt
Rem Your commands go below here.
Echo( You Selected "!Option[%Opt%]!"&Pause
```

*Your options are simply listed within your batch file prepended with a malformed label, `::`, which means the batch file will not run them, but they can be read. The `Set /P` input is checked against those which have been dynamically defined as variables, and only continues when valid input was entered. The string assigned to the chosen variable can be retrieved using delayed expansion as `!Option[%Opt%]!`, I have added an example command line to show you it in use. As a final note, the options can be moved to any position in the script.*

Answer (score 1):

Using `choice.exe` instead of `set /p` avoids any checking for validity as the input is unambiguous.
When using more than 9 options use also letters to stay with single key input.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\30\SO_55920303.cmd
@echo off
:Loop
echo [1] Option 1
echo [2] Option 2
echo [3] Option 3
echo [4] Option 4
echo [5] Option 5
echo [6] Option 6
echo [7] Option 7
echo [8] Option 8
echo [9] Option 9
echo [A] Option 10
echo [Q] quit
choice /C 123456789AQ /M "Enter option"
if errorlevel 11 exit /B 0
echo You chose Option %ErrorLevel%
Timeout /t 3 >Nul
goto :loop
```